# LIKE AND IN in LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, contains

I want to filter the result which does not contain xxx, yyy, zzz, etc.
I tried to use Array to filter out which I don't want, but it doesn't filter and return rows as usual.

```
string[] ExcludeCourses = new string[] {"Functional Skills", "Key Skills"};        
gvProgrammes.DataSource = offerings.Where(o => o.OfferingStatusID == 1
                          && o.OfferingTypeID != 3
                          && !ExcludeCourses.Contains(o.CourseName));
```

Finally I ended up writing like the following for each entry. Is there better way to do that?

```
offerings.Where(o => o.OfferingStatusID == 1
                 && o.OfferingTypeID != 3
                 && !o.CourseName.Contains("Functional Skills")
                 && !o.CourseName.Contains("Key Skills")
                 && !o.CourseName.Contains("Employer Rights and Responsibilities"));
```

The following are the examples of CourseName which I want to exclude:

- Apprenticeship CG Cert Functional Skills Eng L2 (Business Admin)
- Apprenticeship CG Cert Functional Skills Eng L2 (WBL-Engineering)
- Apprenticeship CG Key Skills AON 2 Apprenticeship CG Key Skills AON 1
- Award in Employment Rights and Responsibilities (QCF)

Comment: What does "no success" mean?

Comment: Looks like your first code is correct, what do you mean by "no success"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `Contains` is `Enumerable.Contains`: "this sequence of strings contains this string"

Your second `Contains` are `String.Contains`: "this string contains this other string as a substring".

The following is "this sequence of strings contains a string which this string contains as a substring":

```
string[] ExcludeCourses = new string[] {
    "Functional Skills",
    "Key Skills",
    "Employer Rights and Responsibilities" };
gvProgrammes.DataSource = offerings.Where(o => o.OfferingStatusID == 1
    && o.OfferingTypeID != 3
    && !ExcludeCourses.Any(ec => o.CourseName.Contains(ec)));
```

The `Any` call is basically doing the same as your repeated manual `String.Contains` calls.